# How to use Ninject.MockingKernel?

Tags: mocking, ninject

I'm trying to use Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq. I've 2 problems:

1. I've to register all the types I want to mock. If I don't do that, the parameterless constructor of my class is called and that's not the purpose of an automocker
2. It seems that even if the mock is called, the verification failed. Look at the following sample

Sample Code:

```
//Arrange
var kernel = new Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq.MoqMockingKernel();
kernel.Bind<ClassUnderTest>().ToSelf();
kernel.Bind<ILogger>().ToMock();
kernel.GetBindings(typeof(ILogger));
//Act
var sut = kernel.Get<ClassUnderTest>();
sut.DoSomething();//Logger.Log is called inside that method
//Assert
var mock = kernel.GetMock<ILogger>();
mock.Verify(x => x.Log(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Comment: Dont forget to look at autofixture and autofixture.automoq in this space - @Mark Seemann's posts regarding them will teach you useful things too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For self bindable types such as non-abstract classes an instance of the class is returned by default. The intention behind that is to make the most common use case easy, where a resolve of a class is the object under test and all dependencies are defined as interfaces.

Using classes as a dependency is uncommon as it only allows mocking of virtual methods. As said above this uncommon scenario is more complicated to make the common one as easy as possible.

Interfaces on the other hand don't need any binding.

If you want to mock classes you have to define

```
// note the scope so that you can access it later again
kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToMock().InSingletonScope(); 
var mock = kernel.GetMock<Foo>()
```

Comment: Ok. I was missing to InSingletonScope. Thanks.

Comment: @Remo Gloor Hi :) , I have implemented repository pattern for my project with similar structure as http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application I am preparing for NUnit, Ninject mocking kernel based unit testing. When i mock my application service ( inside BLL layer ) i get the object but then none of the tests succeed, so i suspect my code is wrong I got this `kernel.Mock<IApplicationService>()` where `ApplicationService ( constructor injection)` is implementation of `IApplicationService`

Comment: I need to Mock an object and verify one of its method. (Unit test that method). The problem is the method is trying accessing an object from Ninject. Would Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq be helpful?